Wrong subscription being used when applying terraform with azure
I am trying to learn terraform, by creating a kubernetes cluster and a container registry in azure and giving the kubernetes cluster pull access to the container registry.
I have manually created a service principal with a custom role and authenticated it like they do in the terraform azure totorial. The custom role has all contributor permissions along with the following
Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read
Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write
Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/delete
Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/read
Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/write
Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/delete

And I have correctly set the env vars. When I then try to terraform apply the following file:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.104.2"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {

  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "myRG"
  location = "North Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "mycr"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                 = "Basic"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "myAKS"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "myAKS"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

# Attach the container registry to the kubernetes cluster
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aksPullFromAcr" {
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
}

I get the following error. The weird thing being that the subscription id is pointing to the wrong subscription
Error: retrieving Kubernetes Cluster (Subscription: "<wrong_subscription_id>"
│ Resource Group Name: "myRG"
│ Kubernetes Cluster Name: "myAKS"): unexpected status 403 (403 Forbidden) with error: AuthorizationFailed: The client '<client_id>' with object id '<client_id>' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/read' over scope '/subscriptions/<wrong_subscription_id>/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myAKS' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

I have tried to make a new service principal, but that didn't help.
What am I doing wrong here?

How are you authenticating to the azurerm provider? Are you using environment variables as per Set your environment variables?

Yes, I have set the four environment variables

I have also tried setting them directly in the terraform provider block, but that didn't help either

Are you sure you've assigned the custom role to the right service principal?
Also, Try assigning the service principal the Contributor role to the subscription, to see if it works.

Also, how/where are you running terraform plan/apply commands? In a pipeline? In your local machine? How have you set your environment variables? Try echoing the subscription ID and other variables in the same script/terminal just before running your terraform commands, to ensure you've set them properly.

Hi @Norse,  The above error usually occurs when the terminal is already logged in with another subscription. Check the login status by using az account show. If logged in, log out using az logout


I get the following error. The weird thing being that the subscription id is pointing to the wrong subscription.

If you are authenticating Terraform with the service principal by setting the environment variables and Terraform is going to another subscription instead of the correct subscription specified in the environment variables, you need to check the following steps.

Check if terminal is already logged in with a different account. You may check the login status by using the command: az account show. If logged in, kindly log out using az logout and try executing the terraform apply command.

Make sure to check the CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SUBSCRIPTION_ID, and TENANT_ID that are configured in the environment variables for authentication are the same.

To set to correct subscription, run the below cmd.


az account set --subscription  "your current Sub_ID"


If you are still facing an error, you may also try logging in with the service principal using the Azure CLI.

az login --service-principal -u CLIENT_ID -p CLIENT_SECRET --tenant TENANT_ID

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  tenant_id         = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
  client_id         = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  client_secret     = "ixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "myRG"
  location = "North Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "sampleacr"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                 = "Basic"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "myAKS"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "myAKS"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aksPullFromAcr" {
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
}

Terraform init
As there is no account logged in to the terminal, Terraform is authenticating with the service principal specified in the provider.

Terraform apply


I ended up deleting the terraform.tfstate file which fixed the issue.
The az account show already showed the right subscription, and the other solutions didn't help either.
